# emberjs - Conditionally rendering templates within a larger template

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, routes, render

Ember Community Assemble!

I want to conditionally {{render ''}} small templates inside of the application.hbs sidebar but the content of that sidebar depends on which model's hbs we are routed to. For instance, the contents of the 'permit' sidebar would be different than that of the 'profile' sidebar.

Right now I am only able to render all of the sidebar contents at once regardless of what model.hbs is chosen.

```
<!-- Right Sidebar in application.hbs START -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="super-super-float-right-col">
      <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="super-float-right-col">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="float-right-col">
          {{render 'applicant'}} <!-- only available to '/person/#' -->
          {{render 'location'}} <!--  only available to '/permit/#' -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- Right Sidebar END -->

    <div class="The rest of the content">
      {{outlet}} <!--inserts the rest of the html into the main content container -->
    </div>
```

I don't want both 'applicant' and 'location' to be rendered at the same time as they are above, and I want to data inside of 'applicant' to change depending on the id # of 'person'. The same relationship applies to 'location' inside of 'permit.hbs'

```
VpcYeoman.PermitRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render({ render:'location'});
    }
});
```

Application_route.js is blank for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Although 1.2.0 introduced the ability to use properties for template name in `{{view}}` it does not work for `{{render}}` yet.</del>

So your options are to use `{{view}}` if you can, or a series of `{{#if}}` in the template, or a component/view to wrap the choice of what to render (one way to do this would be to have a template for each render, and a choice view that binds templateName property to the parentController property that determines which should be displayed)

[Here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/acoVirE/7/edit) is a jsbin that I used to experiment.

Comment: Thanks, Michael! Does currentSidebar imply that I should also be adding a currentSidebar.hbs file to render in application.hbs?

Comment: I just checked, and it was 1.2.0 that `{{view someProperty}}` got fixed, and it **does not work** for `{{render someProperty}}`

Comment: What would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: I misread the changelog, you still can't dynamically pass a view to `{{view}}` either. So you have to either wrap the choice in a view or component, or put `{{#if}}`s in your sidebar template. I added a jsbin that shows wrapping the choice in a view.

Comment: the currentSub and currentRenderSub are related to 'mary' but how would I make the value change to 'bob' when I clicked a {{link-to 'bob'}} on the application/index page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41996/discussion-between-michael-johnston-and-ian-steffy)